# SQL - Max() value from the group is not working

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, max, window-functions

Image1: Sample Data

[image]

Image2: Incorrect Output

[image]

Image3: Desired Output

[image]

Query: I'm trying to query the Maximum value from column (Median_Percentage) by the Class_Name and Customer (image1 sample data)

Issue: the query is showing all customers instead of the one that has the Max median value (image2 incorrect result). It is calculating the Max() correctly but the query is putting the value for all the Customers instead of the one that has that Max value within Class_Name

What I need is only the Class_Name which has the Max(Median_Percentage) and show the customer. (image3 desired output)

```
Select  
       distinct  
        C.Class_Name,
        C.Customer,
        C.Max_Median_Percentage

        

FROM (
   
    SELECT 
        
        B.Class_Name,
        
        case (when B.Median_Percentage =  Max(B.Median_Percentage) OVER(PARTITION By B.Class_Name ORDER BY B.Median_Percentage desc  )
            then B.Customer
        end as Customer,

        Max(B.Median_Percentage) OVER(PARTITION By B.Class_Name ORDER BY B.Median_Percentage desc  ) as Max_Median_Percentage

    FROM (
        
        SELECT 
  
            
            A.Class_Name,
            A.Customer,
            A.Date_Time
            
            A.Median_Percentage

        From table1 as A

    ) as B


) as C
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I'm not sure what the SQL has to do with the question, which seems pretty clear by itself.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thanks! I have added tags for the database. I've also simplified the query that I'm working on, hoping it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `percentile_cont()` if your database does not directly support a "median" function:

```
select t.*,
       boot_time / percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by boot_time) over (partition by classid)
from t;
```

If your database doesn't have the `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()` function, you can get very close using a simple `ntile()`:

```
select t.*,
       boot_time / max(case when tile = 1 then boot_time end) over (partition by classid)
from (select t.*,
             ntile(2) over (partition by classid order by boot_time) as tile
      from t
     ) t
```

This works exactly if there are an odd number of rows in the `classid`.  For even numbers, it is off by 1.  You can handle that easily, but with more complication:

```
select t.*,
       (boot_time /
        (( max(case when tile_asc = 1 then boot_time end) over (partition by classid) / 2 +
           max(case when tile_desc = 1 then boot_time end) over (partition by classid)
         ) / 2
        )
       )
from (select t.*,
             ntile(2) over (partition by classid order by boot_time) as tile_asc,
             ntile(2) over (partition by classid order by boot_time desc) as tile_desc
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, percentile_cont() is not applicable in my database

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful -

### Load the test data provided

```scala
val df = spark.sql(
      """
        |select Class_Name, Customer, Date_Time, Median_Percentage
        |from values
        |   ('ClassA', 'A', '6/13/20', 64550),
        |   ('ClassA', 'B', '6/6/20', 40200),
        |   ('ClassB', 'F', '6/20/20', 26800),
        |   ('ClassB', 'G', '6/20/20', 18100)
        |  T(Class_Name, Customer, Date_Time, Median_Percentage)
      """.stripMargin)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      * |Class_Name|Customer|Date_Time|Median_Percentage|
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      * |ClassA    |A       |6/13/20  |64550            |
      * |ClassA    |B       |6/6/20   |40200            |
      * |ClassB    |F       |6/20/20  |26800            |
      * |ClassB    |G       |6/20/20  |18100            |
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Class_Name: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- Customer: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- Date_Time: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- Median_Percentage: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```

### find the max `Median_Percentage` row by `Class_Name`

```scala
    df.groupBy("Class_Name")
      .agg(max(struct($"Median_Percentage", $"Date_Time", $"Customer")).as("struct"))
      .selectExpr("Class_Name", "struct.Customer", "struct.Date_Time", "struct.Median_Percentage")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      * |Class_Name|Customer|Date_Time|Median_Percentage|
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      * |ClassA    |A       |6/13/20  |64550            |
      * |ClassB    |F       |6/20/20  |26800            |
      * +----------+--------+---------+-----------------+
      */
```